# Spark query have something wrong because the processing blocks in a a stage and stays there blocked until the disk get full

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

Im executing this query below on spark but its not working. When arrives at the stage 13 it blocks. And the disk space is increasing while is blocked in the same stage doint nothing and then when the disk get full. Something is wrong with the query, do you see what is wrong in the spark query?

First I create a view in hive:

```
create view q2_min_ps_supplycost as
select
    p_partkey as min_p_partkey,
    min(ps_supplycost) as min_ps_supplycost
from
    part,
    partsupp,
    supplier,
    nation,
    region
where
    p_partkey = ps_partkey
    and s_suppkey = ps_suppkey
    and s_nationkey = n_nationkey
    and n_regionkey = r_regionkey
    and r_name = 'EUROPE'
group by
    p_partkey;
```

Then the query used in spark with hivecontext:

```
 select
        s_acctbal,
        s_name,
        n_name,
        p_partkey,
        p_mfgr,
        s_address,
        s_phone,
        s_comment
    from
        part,
        supplier,
        partsupp,
        nation,
        region,
        q2_min_ps_supplycost
    where
        p_partkey = ps_partkey
        and s_suppkey = ps_suppkey
        and p_size = 37
        and p_type like '%COPPER'
        and s_nationkey = n_nationkey
        and n_regionkey = r_regionkey
        and r_name = 'EUROPE'
        and ps_supplycost = min_ps_supplycost
        and p_partkey = min_p_partkey
    order by
        s_acctbal desc,
        n_name,
        s_name,
        p_partkey
    limit 100;
```

Comment: Well you are joining a lot of tables together. How big are the tables? And can you include a screenshot of the DAG, so we can see what's in stage 13?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can devide the query in multiple queries so you just join two tables in every one to get the same result in the last one, this will minimize the size of the intermidiate files and should avoid blocking.